# Hash password before saving with Laravel Backpacker

Tags: php, laravel, crud, laravel-backpack

A simple question: **how do I modify (hash) the request value before saving it with Laravel Backpacker CRUD admin?**

As far as i understand, it should be done somewhere before these methods are executed in the crud controller:

```
public function store(StoreRequest $request)
{
    return parent::storeCrud();
}

public function update(UpdateRequest $request)
{
    return parent::updateCrud();
}
```

but I have no idea how to do it correctly.

*Edit*: the request is not a `Request` object, but rather `StoreRequest` or `UpdateRequest` that looks something like this:
[image]

***Fix***:

```
public function update(UpdateRequest $request)
{
    // Hash password before save
    if (!empty($request->password)) {
        $request->offsetSet('password', Hash::make($request->password));
    }

    return parent::updateCrud($request); // <-- Pass the modified request, otherwise the CRUD reads it again from post data
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update $request values using the [offsetSet](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_offsetGet) method

```
$request->offsetSet('name', $newName);
```

**Edit:** To update user password you can do something like this:

```
public function update_password(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);

    if (Hash::check($request->old_password, $user->password)) {
        $user->fill([
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
        ])->update();

        return redirect()->back()->with('message' => 'Your password has been updated.');
    }
    else {
        return redirect()->back()->with('message' => 'The password entered do not match our records.');
    }
}
```

I did not check the code but it should work. Now update it to your needs.

Comment: This looks promising, but how do I get the current value? I'd need `$request->offsetSet('password', Hash::make($request_value))`;

Comment: I guess you are trying to update user password. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I need to hash the password before saving

Comment: The method is not needed here this time. I updated my question with the final fix.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking about how to modify data in `$request` variable, you can just do this:

```
$request->property = 'New value';
```

Also, you can add data to reuqest itself (not into variable):

```
request()->request->add(['key' => 'value']);
```

Comment: It's not a regular Laravel request, it's `StoreRequest ` or `UpdateRequest ` object, that looks different. I'll update the question shortly.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was sure I checked that option and it didn't work. Feel stupid now. Thank you.

Comment: This changes the request value, but ends up saving the original plain-text value.

Comment: Try `request()->request->add(['key' => value]);`

Comment: I solved it. The Backpacker CRUD by default doesn't passes the $request variable. Instead it just re-reads from the POST. I fixed it by simply adding $request in the call: `return parent::updateCrud($request)`